# Postgresql insert ptoblem on two self referenced tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, double

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  key character varying NOT NULL,
  registerdate timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  folder_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE folders (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('folders_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    enc_name character varying(500),
    small_name character varying(50),
    owner integer NOT NULL,
    master boolean DEFAULT false
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY folders
    ADD CONSTRAINT folders_owner_fkey FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY users
    ADD CONSTRAINT folder_c_id FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folders(id);
```

Table users references folder and folders references users
Every user have his own master folder and every folder belongs to some user. When a new user is created, a new folder need to be created too. But columns users.folder_id(NOT NULL) and folders.owner(NOT NULL) are both not null.
So if I wanna create new user entry I need a folder already created, and if I wanna create a new folder I need an user already created.
How can I create them?

Comment: Your database design is wrong. If you have one to many relationship, you have to define a foreign key column from the key table in table which contains multiple instances of another entity. If you have many to many relationship so you need to have a table in between, which contains foreign key from both tables.

Comment: just make one of the attributes nullable.